# How to prove this statement in terms of set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Before I start with some statements, I want to tell you that I'm begginner in set theory and if I use notation improperly or say some nonsense feel free to correct me.

Let $P$ be the binary relation of **equivalence** of the set $M$, i.e.

$$P \subset M \times M$$

Let's denote $P\langle x\rangle$ in the following way (Actually I don't know if there a term for this definition because I didn't find it on the internet meanwhile I was taught this on russian):

$$P\langle x\rangle = \{y : (x, y) \in P\}$$

The statement to proof:

$$M = \bigcup_{x \in M} P\langle x\rangle $$

So, this statement seems to me very reasonable, but I haven't done any set theory proof in my life, so have no idea how to prove this statement formally. Any clues to start with?

UPD:

Actually, I don't understand what does it mean to make a set from binary relations. For example if I have only relations P = {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}, how can I restore the required set? Set is the collection of ELEMENTS. not the relations? But from relations I know there are two elements 0 and 1? So this is the way to restore the set from relations?

Initial thought: since $P$ is relation of equivalince there is a pair $(x,x)$ for all $x \in M$ and therefore I can restore the initial set?

Comment: Your P⟨x⟩ is the *range* of relation $P$ ?

Comment: IMO it is not true... $M = \{ 0,1 \}$ and $P= \{ (0,0) \}$. $P(0)= \{ 0 \}$ and thus $\bigcup_{x \in M}P(x)$ has only the element $0$; therefore, it is not equal to $M$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you are right. $P$ is have to be relation of equivalence, I guess. corrected

Comment: Update: a set $M = \{ 0,1 \}$ and the corresponding cartesian product $M \times M = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) \}$ is the set of **all** pairs.

Comment: A binary relation $P$ is a *subset* of $M \times M$ so we can have some but not all the pairs, like in my example above: $P = \{ (0,0) \} \subseteq M \times M$.

Comment: You can "restore" $M$ from $M \times M$ but not - in general - from $P$ because $P$ is a subset of $M \times M$ "carved out" from it according to some rule (listing or specification).

Comment: See [Binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation)

Comment: For an [Equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) it works: every element of $M$ occurs "somewhere" and thus $M = \{ x \mid (x,x) \in P \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I got it, thanks. Can I reformulate my theorem as proving that $\{x | (x, x) \in P\} = \cup_{x\in M} P\langle x\rangle$ (actually this seems a little obvious since RHS is set of all possible pairs and then RHS $\subseteq$ P? (RHS - right-hand side)

Comment: $RHS = P$, not $RHS \subseteq P$ (improper notation usage, I thought $\subseteq$ means equallity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revised some notations of the OP which will show soon. First, we usually call $[x]$ the class of elements equivalent to $x$ in $M$. Now we show the statement.

*Proof.* We show it in two directions:

$(\supseteq)$ It's obvious.

$(\subseteq)$ Suppose $x\in M$. Since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, then $x\sim x$, and so $x\in [x]$. Therefore $x\in\bigcup_{x\in M}[x]$.